# Does start-process command has anything to do with free disk space losing automatically?

Tags: powershell, diskspace

I am using 
start "D:\file path" in windows powershell ise
to access various locations in my PC.

However I noticed that my free disk space in d drive is automatically decreasing. (my c drive is in small 120 gb ssd).

Does start-process command has anything to do with free disk space losing automatically? Or Why disk space automatically decreases?

Comment: What processes are you launching with `Start-Process`?  I think it is more likely that they are using the disk space than `Start-Process` itself.

Comment: I am simply using
start "filepath" # to open folders

Comment: Simply put, no, it does not. It's the only goal is to start X app or app and file or open a file with its default app, as defined by Windows.